# Mysql, partitioning with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate-functions, partitioning

My partitioned tables are described as such:

```
 CREATE TABLE `event_data` (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  Timestamp int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  CurrentDate date NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_index` (`id`),
  KEY `ix_filter` (`Action`,`Location`),
  KEY `ix_time` (`Timestamp`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1176568 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(CurrentDate)
(PARTITION p20130106 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-06') ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p20130113 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-13') ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p20130120 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-20') ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

I am trying to execute the following queries:

`explain partitions select min(Timestamp) from event_data where CurrentDate < "2013-01-06";`

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | event_data | p20130106  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 512983 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

And

`explain partitions select min(Timestamp) from event_data;`

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
```

It seems that without specifying the partition the query is faster ( i know that the minimum is always in the first partition)

`select min(Timestamp) from event_data where CurrentDate < "2013-01-06";`

```
+----------------+
| min(Timestamp) |
+----------------+
|     1321747200 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

And

`select min(Timestamp) from event_data ;`

```
+----------------+
| min(Timestamp) |
+----------------+
|     1321747200 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Shouldn't the query with specifying the partition be faster since it need to look on the minimum only in single partition as opposed to the minimum searched over all partitions?

It seems as the Timestamp index is not used when indicating the partition, but why??? i have MYI file for every partition file, i was sure that indexes are built for each such file...

I also know that the indexes are used in different select queries without the aggregation functions (benchmark testing).

**UPDATE**

I have found this bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66187, this is relevant to my question.

Comment: @ypercube, yes it appears in my definition of table (attached in the question)

Comment: I haven't played with partitions much but the answer is probably that. In the second query, the index is used and the minimum can be found really fast. In the first query, it doesn't use the index but scans the whole (first) partition.

Comment: @ypercube, i thought so also, but then for what purpose do we have indexes per partition ??? i thought we have index tree per partition file or at least why i have MYI file for each partition

Comment: Can you try running the first query again? Does it always take 0.16 seconds? And with the reverse order, the second and the then the first query? Caching may explain the timings.

Comment: And whether this executes faster? `select min(Timestamp) from event_data FORCE INDEX (ix_time) where CurrentDate < '2013-01-06';`

Comment: @ypercube, first of all thanks for your help. 1. the order of queries don't make any difference, for the second query it takes between 0.18 and 0.15, for the first one 0.00 always. 2. Force index doesn't help

Comment: @ypercube, it seems that this bug report is relevant : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66187

Comment: Nice. You can post this as an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a serious bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66187  that describes the same issue. I have added a comment to this Bug